# How do you quickly find the URL for a Win32 API on MSDN?

Tags: windows, winapi

How do you quickly find the URL for a Win32 API on MSDN?  It's easy for .NET methods -- just add the method name (for example, System.Byte.ToString) to http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/.

However, for Win32 APIs (say GetLongPathName), this doesn't work: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/GetLongPathName.

I want to be able to use the URL in code comments or documentation.  So the URL one gets with an MSDN or Google search (for example, http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa364980.aspx) isn't really what I'm looking for.  I'd really like my code comments to look something like:

// blah blah blah.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/GetLongPathName for more information.

What's the magic pixie dust for Win32 APIs?  Or does it only work for .NET methods?

Answer (score 5):

Google might be your best bet.  I know the msdn site search has time and again pointed me in the wrong direction, but a quick switch to Google ("GetLongPathName site:msdn.microsoft.com") never steers me wrong.

Comment: Yes this works to find the URL but it somewhat misses the point of the question.  I'd like to have an easy-to-read URL that can be added to comments or documentation.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW if you have the **MSDN** installed locally on your machine the [Zeus](http://www.zeusedit.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=3758) editor has a feature to search the local copy of the **MSDN**.

For example, placing the cursor on the **GetLongPathName** word within a text document and using the [Zeus](http://www.zeusedit.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=3758) Help, **Quick Help, Current Word** menu, the following **MSDN** page gets loaded:

*ms-help://MS.VSCC.v80/MS.MSDN.vAug06.en/fileio/fs/getlongpathname.htm*

Answer (score 0):

I am using [Linkify](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/macros/Linkify.aspx) by *cough* me, which lets you link

```
// see msdn:GetLongPathName
```

to the google search japollock mentions.

Answer (score 0):

You could use MSDN search.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Search/en-US/?Refinement=86&Query=**GetLongPathName**

`Refinement=86` stands for Win32 search.

Answer (score 0):

MSDN GET api `(I don't know how new this is)`

```
"https://learn.microsoft.com/api/search?locale=en-us&scoringprofile=semantic-captions&%24top=1&search=" functionName
```

returns json like such:

```json
{
    "results": [
        {
            "title": "KeClearEvent function (wdm.h) - Windows drivers",
            "url": "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/nf-wdm-keclearevent",
            "displayUrl": {
                "content": "/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/nf-wdm-keclearevent",
                "hitHighlights": [
                    {
                        "start": 41,
                        "length": 12
                    }
                ]
            },
            "description": "The KeClearEvent routine sets an event to a not-signaled state.",
            "descriptions": [
                {
                    "content": "KeClearEvent function (wdm.h) Article 04/18/2022 2 minutes to read In this article The KeClearEvent routine sets an event to a not-signaled state.",
                    "hitHighlights": [
                        {
                            "start": 0,
                            "length": 12
                        },
                        {
                            "start": 87,
                            "length": 12
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "content": "For better performance, use KeClearEvent unless the caller uses the value returned by KeResetEvent to determine what to do next.",
                    "hitHighlights": [
                        {
                            "start": 28,
                            "length": 12
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "lastUpdatedDate": "2022-04-18T04:31:00+00:00",
            "breadcrumbs": []
        }
    ],
    "spellingCorrection": [],
    "scopeRemoved": false,
    "count": 18,
    "nextLink": "https://learn.microsoft.com/api/Search?locale=en-us\u0026search=KeClearEvent\u0026$skip=1\u0026$top=1",
    "srcheng": "02"
}
```

if you want *really* fast, you can bind it to a hotkey
[AutohotkeyV2](https://www.autohotkey.com/v2/)

```
#SingleInstance force
ListLines 0
KeyHistory 0
SendMode "Input" ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir A_ScriptDir ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.

linkFromName(functionName) {
    json:=downloadToVar("https://learn.microsoft.com/api/search?locale=en-us&scoringprofile=semantic-captions&%24top=1&search=" functionName)
    obj:=JSON_parse(json)
    if (obj.results.Length) {
        RegExMatch(obj.results[1].title, ".*?(?=\s|$)", &OutputVar)
        if (OutputVar.0 = functionName) {
            validUrl:=obj.results[1].url
        } else if (OutputVar.0 = functionName "W" || OutputVar.0 = functionName "A") {
            validUrl:=SubStr(obj.results[1].url, 1, -1) "w"
        }
        ; A_Clipboard:=validUrl
        Run validUrl
    }
}

; linkFromName("GetLongPathNameW") ;works
; linkFromName("GetLongPathName") ;works
linkFromName(A_Clipboard)

Exitapp

f3::Exitapp

downloadToVar(url) {
    whr := ComObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
    whr.Open("GET", url, true)
    whr.SetRequestHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)")
    whr.Send()
    ; Using 'true' above and the call below allows the script to remain responsive.
    whr.WaitForResponse()
    return whr.ResponseText
}

JSON_parse(str) {

    c_:=1

    return JSON_value()

    JSON_value() {

        char_:=SubStr(str, c_, 1)
        Switch char_ {
            case "{":
                obj_:=Map()
                ;object
                c_++
                loop {
                    skip_s()
                    if (SubStr(str, c_, 1) == "}") {
                        c_++
                        return obj_
                    }

                    ; key_:=JSON_objKey()
                    ; a or "a"
                    if (SubStr(str, c_, 1) == "`"") {
                        RegExMatch(str, "(?:\\.|.)*?(?=`")", &OutputVar, c_ + 1)
                        key_:=RegExReplace(OutputVar.0, "\\(.)", "$1")
                        c_+=OutputVar.Len
                    } else {
                        RegExMatch(str, ".*?(?=[\s:])", &OutputVar, c_)
                        key_:=OutputVar.0
                        c_+=OutputVar.Len
                    }

                    c_:=InStr(str, ":", true, c_) + 1
                    skip_s()

                    value_:=JSON_value()
                    obj_[key_]:=value_
                    obj_.DefineProp(key_, {Value: value_})

                    skip_s()
                    if (SubStr(str, c_, 1) == ",") {
                        c_++, skip_s()
                    }
                }
            case "[":
                arr_:=[]
                ;array
                c_++
                loop {
                    skip_s()
                    if (SubStr(str, c_, 1) == "]") {
                        c_++
                        return arr_
                    }

                    value_:=JSON_value()
                    arr_.Push(value_)

                    skip_s()
                    char_:=SubStr(str, c_, 1)
                    if (char_ == ",") {
                        c_++, skip_s()
                    }
                }
            case "`"":
                RegExMatch(str, "(?:\\.|.)*?(?=`")", &OutputVar, c_ + 1)
                unquoted:=RegExReplace(OutputVar.0, "\\(.)", "$1")
                c_+=OutputVar.Len + 2
                return unquoted
            case "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9":
                RegExMatch(str, "[0-9.]*", &OutputVar, c_)
                c_+=OutputVar.Len
                return Number(OutputVar.0)
            case "t":
                ;"true"
                c_+=4
                return {a:1}
            case "f":
                ;"false"
                c_+=5
                return {a:0}
            case "n":
                ;"null"
                c_+=4
                return {a:-1}


        }
    }

    skip_s() {
        RegExMatch(str, "\s*", &OutputVar, c_)
        c_+=OutputVar.Len
    }
}
```